# Clear Select2 Search Input When No Results Found

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2-4

I am using jQuery Select2 version 4.0.13.
I would like to auto clear the search text box when the No Results Found displays.
Sort of a reset of the dropdown options.
Currently I use scanned barcodes that match the dropdown option values.
If I scan in a barcode that is not in the list the scanned barcode text remains in the search display. Then if I scan in an acceptable barcode it just appends to the end of what ever is in the search text box. If I manually clear the search text box it will work as expected. I have the following code but where the alert is I need to have syntax to clear the search text thus resetting to dropdown options.

```
$('.packageDropDown').select2({
    dropdownCssClass: 'ui-widget ui-jqdialog zclass',
    width: 350,
    "language": {
        "noResults": function(searchedTerm) {
            alert("No Match");

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=select2+clear+search+no+result+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

In `noResults`, remove the value from `.select2-search__field` with `$('.select2-search__field').val('');` and trigger the `input` event.

```js
$('.packageDropDown').select2({
  dropdownCssClass: 'ui-widget ui-jqdialog zclass',
  width: 350,
  "language": {
    "noResults": function(searchedTerm) {
      $(".packageDropDown").val("AL").trigger("change");
      $(".select2-search__field").val("").trigger("input");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="packageDropDown" name="state">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does not do exactly what I was expecting. I changed your code slightly to .val(0) since this is my default(prompt) value. What I am seeing with this code is the search field does not clear the unmatched value and the drop down does not display the option list unless I click the list.

Comment: Hi @SteveDyke can you clarify what issue you need to fix?

Comment: Simply, if a value is typed into the Select2 search box that does not match any of the option values, in lieu of returning the No Results Found, reset the Select2 to its initial state which is: expanded to show the options, value zero selected, and the cursor in an empty search field.

Comment: Tried putting this $('.packageDropDown').select2('open'); in the noResults function and it still does not refresh the Select2 display.

Comment: @SteveDyke I understand your problem and updated my code. can you check it once :)